# starting up radio and one led

Tags: python, radio

I'm using this in as my `/etc/init.d/pirateRadio.sh`

the Radio does play a wav with this in the rc.local

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin
sleep 10
(
 exec &>> /var/log/my_rc_local.log
 cd /home/pi/pifm/pifm && ./pifm left_right.wav 100.1 stereo
) &
```

I had the led working before I added the above by itself in the rc.local

```
# Light ON AIR LED
sudo python /home/pi/pifm/pifm/ledon.py &
```

but now I am trying to combine both, in a shell and i am lost.
I usually get `[src/libout123/wav.c:755] error: flushing failed: Broken pipe`

This is what I have craeted for pirateRadio.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/pirateRadio.sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:              pirateRadio.sh
# Required-Start:        $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:         $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:         2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:          0 1 6
# Short-Description:     Runs radio
# Description:           Runs my radio.
### END INIT INFO

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin
sleep 20

# This works in the rc.local
# (
#  exec &>> /var/log/my_rc_local.log
#  cd /home/pi/pifm/pifm && ./pifm - 100.1
# ) &
###


case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "StARRRRRRRting Pirate Radio"
        sudo /usr/bin/mpg123 -4 -s -Z /home/pi/Music/* | cd /home/pifm/pifm/ && sudo ./pifm - 100.1
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping Pirate Radio"
        killall pifm
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/pirateRadio.sh start|stop"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

# Light ON AIR LED
sudo python /home/pi/pifm/pifm/ledon.py &

exit 0
```

---

Oh and additionally, if I correct, "esac" to "case"
I get

```
sudo ./pirateRadio.sh start
./pirateRadio.sh: line 37: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./pirateRadio.sh: line 37: `case '
```

Answer (score 1):

You are piping the output of *mpg123* into *cd*. This won't work as intended. *cd* before the pipeline, or simply use an absolute path to your *pifm* script.

If you absolutely have to *cd* and want to have your main script stay in the same directory, open a sub-shell with parantheses `( commands … )`.

---

Oh, and additionally, you don't *correct* *esac* to *case*. That's reversed intentionally, it's the end of case, just as *fi* is the end of *if*. Oddly *do*/*done* do not follow this convention.